# MySQL Database Design for Prices / Specials

Tags: mysql, database-design

Below is an example of what I need to design in the database:

[image]

There will be an option for a price, and then a special if it has one, and then I was wondering how I could do this if I wanted one of the options to be "FREE".

See also there will be different currencies based on their country.  Here is what I had in mind:

```
id - service_name - price - special_price - eco_friendly - free
1  - Rotate Tires - 9.00  - NULL          - 1            - 1
2  - Service      - 120.00- 100.00        - NULL         - NULL
```

Would that work or is there a better way to do this?  The eco-friendly will just display an icon in the HTML if it is set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the special_price to 0 and let the presentation layer print FREE if the price is 0.

That way you can also do discount calculations and other things so that the price actually drops to 0 and then becomes "FREE" to the customer.

Comment: What if I want to show the original price, like in the screenshot the original price is $9.00 but the special will be FREE.  So then they will never know the original price?